# Identity Server 4 - User Claims empty on linux

Tags: linux, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem:

On Linux server User Claims are not passing from Auth to API. On Windows machine everything works fine (under VS2017 and using CMD)

I have Controller with special authorization attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "identity")]
[Route("routes")]
public class RoutesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string postId, string routeType)
    {
        //
    }
```

In Startup.cs I have provided proper entries:

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("identity"));
});
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("identity", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new IdentityUserRequirement());
    });
});
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IdentityUserHandler>();
```

And created proper class in /Filters directory:

```
public class IdentityUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IdentityUserRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IdentityUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        UserModel user = _userRepository.FindById(context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "userid")?.Value);
        user.IMEI = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "imei")?.Value;
        _userRepository.UpdateUser(user);

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Using Postman I'm calling Auth service to gain access_token, then using that token I'm calling my RoutesController Get method.

On Windows (launching services under VS2015 or launching services via CMD) method returns normal JSON with Routes.

When I've deployed solution on Linux following error appeared:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And is reffering to my IdentityUserHandler class method HandleRequirementAsync to line:

```
user.IMEI = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "imei")?.Value;
```

As far i manager to debug Linux enviroment looks like there is a problem with:

```
AuthorizationHandlerContext context
```

parameter in method HandleRequirementAsync

Collection contex.User.Claims has no elements. On Windows has, on Linux no.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Have the same issue out of nowhere. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have the same issue. And found out it happens whenever the token gets expired. Still trying to found out how to catch that before it reaches `HandleRequirementAsync`

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tests and it looks like this is working only on my developers machine, on:

- Centos
- Win Server 2k8
- Win Sever 2k16

Problem exist